# Workflow Field Update Issue

Tags: workflow, field-update

I need to write a field update on number.
Example - if i enter - 00000.000000/00000-0000

so it should be come in this format - 00.000.000/0000-00

First remove the -, . , /
then
Put the . - / at proper places.

i am trying to use substitute function but not able to properly fix.

Comment: how rigid is the input format? Can there be arbitrary `.` or `/` or `-` ?  or varying numbers of digits ? if yes, you'll most likely need a trigger+Apex

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to go for a `Field Update` in the workflow which takes the field's value and transforms it to another through a formula.

In order to operate with the value you'll find the following functions useful:

- `SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text)`
- `LEFT(text, num_chars)`
- `RIGHT(text, num_chars)`

Regardless, you can find the full docs of the functions available [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/customize_functions.htm).